# How to have a telegram bot join a channel via link?

Tags: telegram-bot, channel

I would like to program a crawler bot which would surf channels and find the message with high view counts.

1. Is it possible to have a bot added to a channel via link?
2. Is it possible for a bot to read messages broadcast in a channel?
3. Is it possible for a bot to read view count value of a message in a channel?

If any of the above questions are possible, what is/are the solution(s)?

Answer (score 6):

1. Only creator/admins can add bots to channels and only as admins.
2. Bots (for now) can't read messages in channels.
3. Bots (for now) can't view any counters in channels.

Finally, for now, bots can only post messages to channels and only if added to channel by creator or admin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.